# Allow users to cast a "reopen" vote before a question is closed

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Controversial feature request I know - but it seems a bit... ridiculous that only five users are required to close a question, and even if 100 experienced users come along who disagree with those close votes, there's nothing they can do about it until the question is closed (and then often we need a big push to do anything about it, hence all the reopen discussions on meta).

A handful of regular users who decide every other question should be closed surely shouldn't have more power than hundreds of other users who decide the questions are fine, and should remain open - yet this is the situation we're in at present.

If a permission were enabled that allowed higher rep users to retract close votes on an "I disagree" basis, even if they (for example) only had the weight of removing half a close vote each, this might help to restore some of this balance.

Comment: This is not something we can deal with at MetaWorkplace.  Try [MetaSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).  This is core SE functionality so not something we can customize just for us.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings SE have declared that requests for changes via MetaSE will be ignored for the time being so not sure that's a worthwhile avenue for the OP.

Comment: "A handful of regular users who decide every other question should be closed surely shouldn't have more power than hundreds of other users who decide the questions are fine, and should remain open - yet this is the situation we're in at present." - right now the best you can do is wait for the "regular users" to put the question on hold, then come back here and ask that it be reopened. I'll happily vote to reopen every question that shouldn't have been closed in the first place. Perhaps others will as well. I know it's silly but there's no alternative now.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as Joe, I try to reopen everything that's been closed for essentially no reason

Comment: Too bad that the closing halts the natural process and growth of posts, dumps them from HNQ (if they were), reduces the interest of readers, prevents users from answering good suggestions, etc...

Comment: We are spending weeks, if not months, complaining about "a handful of regular users who decide every other question should be closed", with different variations of the same issues. However, naming these users is not allowed because... it's a bad thing? And collecting data to verify the distribution of close votes is a no-go because... no moderator can be bothered, even if there are tools to do so? Where is the punchline?

Comment: @Monoandale - IMHO, it would be best to stop trying to "out" folks. It would be better to stop complaining. It would be best to start voting.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere can we vote on testing the validity of the recent flood of similar complaints with a quantitative review?

Comment: @Monoandale - I don't know what that  means. Vote on a review?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere get the VTC data out in the open, and verify if there is any user who is significantly, disproportionately involved in VTC activity as a fraction of her/his overall activity. There must be a way.

Comment: @Monoandale - there's no value in that, in my opinion. Just vote to reopen questions that should be reopened.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I appreciate it.

Comment: @Monoandale I see value in it, at the very least there will be data rather than guesswork, I don't have a problem with people being named, I have come under attack more than once without crying about it. It's a good thing, it gives me a chance to respond and clear the air. On some occasions I have even done a 180 based on negative feedback.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I do the same as you - but it's a massive problem, and that can't be the long term solution. It drives new users away from the site, makes the community look plain hostile to newcomers, and more than once I've had an answer I've typed wasted because the question has gone passed the tipping point of close votes before I could hit the "post" button. In the wake of the "welcome wagon" stuff, I'd have hoped solving this problem would be more of a priority.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere By the time I got to it, it was already protected.

Comment: @berry120 - my hope is that folks who rapidly vote to close questions that should remain open will become discouraged when the question is rapidly reopened - and rethink their actions.

Comment: @Kilisi - it's not hard for anyone to note who has voted to close a question. I'm sure you already know the usernames. There's no need for a special review/query, or public shaming, IMHO.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I hoped for that too. Sadly though, this has been going on long enough that it seems like they're not particularly discouraged (if anything the opposite, it seems to have turned into something akin to a weird game.)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere There is a frequent VTCer that I suspect uses some sort of automated tool based on the speed and frequency with which they find "duplicates".  I doubt this person cares if the stuff they voted on gets reopened because I sincerely doubt they read the question to begin with.

Comment: @Myles - there's no need for a tool if your goal is to find "duplicates" quickly. You just have to want to vote to close often.

Comment: Instead of whining about the questions being closed why not try to open up the official scope of the site.  Then the close votes wont need to pile up on the type of questions you want to ask.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I think the questions being closed are *already* within the official scope of this site.

Comment: @Monoandale Public shaming will probably do little more than make everyone angry at everyone else, and people will take action based on who users are rather than the content. You also seem to be implying that these users are intentionally closing things they know aren't *actually* off-topic, where-as they almost certainly believe their votes are justified. To get people to stop incorrectly closing questions, it seems much more productive to **discuss patterns in the questions themselves** (which no-one has yet done AFAIK), and why/whether that's on topic, rather than singling out close voters.

Comment: If, after such a discussion, a single user keeps close or reopen voting in a way that goes against the **consensus** we reached, you can @ them and link them to the discussion. If that doesn't work, it might be best to just leave them be - there's a reason it takes 5 votes to close a question.

Comment: (I mean patterns appearing in questions, not having the discussion take place in questions)